# Creating tile chart in R

Tags: r, plot

What's the best way to create tile charts in R?

By tile charts I mean something like this, where size and colour of the tiles are determined by variables.

[image]

I looked at `geom_tile` from `ggplot2` but it seems geared more towards regular tiles, or at least require much tweaking to generate something like above.

Comment: Your question still seems very broad.  It's essentially a search request and a product recommendation question; we don't do those here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the package `treemap` that seems to fit the bill.